# How to set timeout for Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, speech-recognition, windows-10-universal

In `.NET` apps, the namespace used for speech recognition is: `System.Speech` and the `timeout` for the speech recognition is set as:

```
recognizer.Timeouts.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 * 60)
```

In `UWP` apps, the namespace used for speech recognition is: `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition`, how I can set up the `timeout` here? let's say I need the voice recognition to stay ready for listening for 1 hour before stop the recognition.

I tried [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizertimeouts.babbletimeout?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1) but did not work with me.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/set-speech-recognition-timeouts)?

Comment: @Romasz what you mentioned did not work with me, it worked with the `System.Speech` namespace only :(